# What order to they go?

Tags: knowledge, english

Below is a list of clues, in no particular order:

- Home
- Forever
- At 7:00 PM
- Frequently
- Annoyingly
- Speedily

One order is the correct order. What is this order, and why is it the "correct" order?

Hint 1:

> Start looking for commonalities in these words. What about them is the same for all words?

Hint 2:

> Note the "Knowledge" tag and the "English" tag. Take this to mean you might need some uncommon knowledge about the English Language itself. I'm a native speaker and I didn't know about this until recently, so I'd expect not everyone knows about it.

Hint 3:

> I actually got this idea from [a recent Stack Overflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/13/tales-from-documentation-write-for-your-dumbest-user/). There's something in there (if you read it long enough) that will help you, though it's not exactly what's going on here. It's very similar, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct order is

> annoyingly, speedily, home, frequently, at 7 PM, forever

because

> this is how adverbs are ordered in English sentences. Excelsior College OWL gives "manner, place, frequency, time [, purpose]" as the default ordering; "annoyingly" can only modify "speedily", and "forever" could go at the end. This could be attached to a clause in this order: "He went annoyingly speedily home frequently at 7 PM ".

(It's possible that there is some amount of reordering that could be done, especially with the word that I placed in the last position. But I believe this is the correct general idea.)

Comment: Definitely the right idea. I was using a list that had more categories, so I had "annoyingly: as something else, and thus further down the list. But I certainly could accept this answer as is. I think I'll wait a bit though and see if someone gets the longer list first.

Comment: Wow, bang on 100k rep! Screenshot that one quickly! Congrats :)